# Flex s:TextArea cannot see softkeyboard

Tags: ios, apache-flex, actionscript, iphone-softkeyboard

I use spark TextArea as my input dialog on my iPad1(IOS 5.1.1).

I use the codes as following

```
<s:HGroup x="5" y="65" left="5" right="5" width="750" height="50">
    <s:TextArea id="inputTextfield" needsSoftKeyboard="true" click="onTextInputClicked(event)"/>
</s:HGroup>
```

I also call function requestSoftKeyboard when click this text area. What's strange is the return value of requestSoftKeyboard is true, However, I cannot see the soft keyboard.

Do I need to setup other stuff?

Comment: What AIR SDK are you using? There is a bug in certain AIR SDKs (3.4 for sure, since I experienced the issue) that prevents the softkeyboard from launching.

Comment: My Air SDK version is 3.6 and My working environment is Flash Builder 4.7 I need to use an ANE, so I think 3.4 should be ok for me. But I  cannot use USB debugger :-)

Comment: No, for sure this bug exists in 3.4 so don't use that one. I never found a solution and ended up dumping Flex altogether shortly after discovering the bug